# Solve $6 = 13 - x - ((13 - x) * .4)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm embarrassed to ask this question. How do I solve this equation?

```
6 = 13 - X - ((13 - X) * .4)
```

My next step would be...

```
6 = 13 - X - (13 * .4) - (X * .4)
```

... but if I plug these two into WolframAlpha, I get different outcomes for X.

Comment: You forgot to distribute. $13-x-0.4*(-x)=13-x+0.4*x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Silynn and Andre say, I forgot a minus sign. My next step should have been...

```
6 = 13 - X - (13 * .4) - (-X * .4)
---- added minus sign ----^-------
```

Thanks!